# Substitute in Vim doesn't seem to work globally?

Tags: vim, macvim

The `global` option in my `substitute` doesn't seem to work. Even when I do substitute with `g` set it substitutes the text only in the current line. If I run it again while staying on the current line which doesn't have any more matches it gives me

> E486: Pattern not found: {patt}

If I go to the next match and run it again it works fine for that line. But there is literally no difference in using `g` and not using it.

Any ideas on what's wrong?

```
printf("abc");
printf("def");
```

Doing `:s/printf/print/g` highlights both the `printf's` but only the replaces the first one. I need to do `n` to go the next match and rerun substitute.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `g` flag is to substitute the pattern multiple times *per line*.

What you're looking for is running the `s///` command for the entire buffer:

```
:%s/pattern/replacement/g
```

Notice the `%` in front of `s///`, to select the entire buffer. It could also be a range of lines like this:

```
:10,21s/pattern/replacement/g
```

to perform the replacement between lines 10 and 21.

Without the `g` flag there, only the first occurrence of pattern will be replaced per line.

Comment: If you don't want to add the g flag manually each time, you can set the option `gdefault`, which will make your searches global by default.

Comment: When using gdefault, keep in mind that adding `/g` to the end will reverse the meaning. So in this case the `/g` will be non global.